# How do I insert more than 8k in an SQL Server text column using REPLICATE()?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've got to write a test that requires large amounts of data to be stored in a text column.

When I try this (insert 2 billion X characters):

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES ( REPLICATE('X', 2000000000) )
```

This is what I get:

```
SELECT *, DATALENGTH(textCol) FROM table
```

> XXXXXXXXXXXXX.... 8000

I was hoping for more than 8000.  Any ideas where I'm going wrong?  My google-fu is failing me.

*Caveat*: Yes, text columns are deprecated.  I'm sure there are lots of very valid and sensible reasons why it's a bad idea to want to use them as bulk data stores.  Assume I'm dealing with a legacy system that happens to have text columns storing large amounts of bulk data and I have to write tests to figure out how my bit of third party code can deal with that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `REPLICATE` function [returns data in the same type as was passed in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174383.aspx). Because you're passing in a normal quoted string, that creates a `varchar` (not to be confused with a `varchar(MAX)`), which has a maximum capacity of 8000 characters.

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES ( REPLICATE(convert(varchar(MAX), 'X'), 2000000000) )
```

I can't let you go without the obligatory recommendation that you use `varchar(MAX)` (or `nvarchar(MAX)`) columns instead of `text`, but this should do the trick. I'm not in front of SSMS right now, but you *may* have to `convert(text, REPLICATE(convert(varchar(MAX), 'X'), 2000000000))`, but I don't think so. Either way, this should do the trick.

Comment: Motivation for his recommendation ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx ): " **ntext**, **text**, and **image** data types will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead."

Answer (score 4):

Just cast inline to a clob datatype (replicate returns same as passed), like this:

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES ( REPLICATE(cast('X' as varchar(max)), 2000000000) )
```

Comment: And just as a note, Adam Robinson's answer below popped up after I posted, his has some additional thought, likely should be considered the better answer since I was lazy and didn't link like he did. Include the inline approach with his answer and you've got a couple of options.

Comment: +1 for doing the same thing I did. I thought of converting after I already posted my answer, I wasn't just poaching yours ;)